# How to add remove !important css with new css

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

bootstrap-next-table` and I am using this table in my project around different places, and I have to override a CSS class in this and I have given my own value.

Now the problem that I am currently facing, one component needs default CSS class. I have to override this class:

```
.table > thead {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Now in one file I need this:

```
.table > thead {
    display: block;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I tried to tidy up the formatting of the question (the word "css" isn't code, for example, and the pronoun "I" should always be capitalised); would you proof-read the edits to check that the question is still correct? I think it's worth noting that your first sentence is incomplete, I left `bootstrap-next-table`, but I can't work out why it's there; what were you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a selector with higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception) and use `!important` in your style declaration. Here's a plain HTML/CSS snippet that you can adapt to Raect's `className` attribute syntax.

```css
.table > thead {
  display: none !important;
}

.table > thead.box {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Second</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<table class="table">
  <thead class="box">
    <tr>
      <th>Third</th>
      <th>Fourth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```